# Validar ingreso de datos duplicados en Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy comenzando en el desarrollo de JavaScript y tengo la siguiente función que almacena filas de datos cada vez que se ejecuta, quisiera agregarle un validador para que no almacene datos repetidos si ya existe en el array (como una búsqueda previa para validar antes de almacenar) caso contrario omitir almacenar en el array.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Lista = [];
        let count = 0;

        function Items_Migrar_OC(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM) {

            if (Item_Seleccionado == "1") {
                Lista[count] = { CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM }
                count++;
            }
            console.log(Lista);
        }
    </script>
```

Evitar esta duplicidad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZADO**
**SOLUCIÓN AL EJEMPLO:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Lista = [];
        var Fila_r = {};
        let count = 0;

        function Items_Migrar_OC(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND, Item_Seleccionado) {
            //alert(Item_Seleccionado);

            var duplicado = false;

            if (Item_Seleccionado == "1") {
                Fila_r = { CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND }

                duplicado = validateUnique(Fila_r)
                alert(duplicado);

                if (duplicado == false){
                    Lista[count] = Fila_r
                    count++;
                }

            }

            console.log(Lista);
        }

        function validateUnique(myObject) {
            return !!Lista.find(i => i.NU_SECU === myObject.NU_SECU)
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: puedes hacer un if que valide primero una busqueda de todo lo de la tabla y luego si los datos que va a ingresar ya existen entonces que no lo haga.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la propiedad que lo hace único? NU_SECU?

Comment: Si la lógica de la búsqueda la tengo clara, mi consulta va más a como puedo contruir esa búsqueda en el array considerando que el NU_SECU es el identificador único.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello puedes usar la función `includes` de `Array`, te dejo un ejemplo con comentarios

```
//Declaras tu lista
var Lista = [];

function Items_Migrar_OC(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM){
    //En esta parte no se que sea 'Item_Seleccionado', lo dejaré así ya que pienso que esa variable está declarada en otra parte de tu código
    if(Item_Seleccionado == "1"){


       //Guardo los datos en un objeto
       var datos = { "CO_EMPR": CO_EMPR, "TI_REQI": TI_REQI, "NU_REQI": NU_REQI, "NU_SECU": NU_SECU, "CO_ITEM": CO_ITEM };

        //Entonces ahora validamos si el elemento está o no
        if(!Lista.includes(datos)){
            //Si no está un, entonces lo insertamos
            Lista.push( datos );
        }
        else{
            //De lo contrario
            console.log("Ese ya está");
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la siguiente lógica:

La función `validateUnique()` recibe un objeto y es comparado con cada item de `myArray` mediante su propiedad `NU_SECU` usando la función `find()`, si existe una coincidencia con esa propiedad entonces se retorna su equivalente en `boolean`(de hecho si encuentra una coincidencia retorna el objeto hallado, pero estoy usando !! para convertirlo a su equivalente boleano).

```js
const myArray = [
  { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 3 },
  { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 5 }
] 

const newObjectOne = { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 5 }
const newObjectTwo = { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 6 }

function validateUnique(myObject) {
  return !!myArray.find(i => i.NU_SECU === myObject.NU_SECU)
}

console.log('newObjectOne exists in array: ', validateUnique(newObjectOne))
console.log('newObjectTwo exists in array: ', validateUnique(newObjectTwo))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió la respuesta!! Una última consulta en la solución de mi ejemplo se verifica que si Item_Seleccionado == "1" valida y registra, como puedo hacer si Item_Seleccionado == "0" y yo puedo ubicar el elemento almacenado en el array y eliminarlo (entiendo que debería ubicar su ubicación y así ejecutar splice... Gracias de antemano..

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear dos funciones, una que determina qué es "ser igual", es decir, cuáles propiedades tienen que ser iguales para que dos objetos se consideren iguales y la otra que itere sobre el arreglo y utilice la función anterior para determinar si ya existe el elemento que se pretende agregar.

Obviamente se pueden mejorar los nombres de tales funciones y la sintaxis si es que trabajases con objetos en lugar de parámetros, pero dadas las condiciones decidí presentarte esta solución:

```
function sonIguales(item,CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM){

    let sonIguales= true;


    sonIguales= sonIguales&& item.CO_EMPR === CO_EMPR;
    sonIguales= sonIguales&& item.TI_REQI === TI_REQI;
    sonIguales= sonIguales&& item.NU_REQI === NU_REQI;
    sonIguales = sonIguales&& item.NU_SECU === NU_SECU;
    sonIguales= sonIguales&& item.CO_ITEM === CO_ITEM;

    return sonIguales;
}

function estaRepetido(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM){

    for(let item of Lista)
    {
        if(sonIguales(item, CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Cada vez que quieras agregar un nuevo elemento, utilizas la segunda función para determinar si ya existe o no.

Answer (score 0):

pudes usar la opcion filter, por ejemplo:

```
var x = [1,3,4,6,9];
```

al aplicar filter:

```
var y = x.filter(x => x == 3);
```

y al obtener el length tendras igual a 1 lo que implica que el número a ingresar está en la lista. Filter puede ser usado dentro de tu listas de objetos como en tu caso quedaría:

```
var y = x.filter(m => m.NU_SECU == NU_SECU)
```